# Reading a Google Calender using a Cron-activated python script

Tags: python, authentication, calendar, cron, oauth2client

being new with python on a raspberry pi, I downloaded the sample for accessing a google calender given here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/ and made it run. Just renamed the original file and wrote some code around it. Script works fine when launched from the command line.

But when calling the script hourly via cron, an additional (or new) authentication is required: I'm told to copy a link to the browser, get the 'success code' and copy this into the raw input line the script is intended to show me. The problem is, that this message is sent to my postbox by cron via email and the script is stopped. So I don't have the chance to enter the 'success code' and have it authenticated.

Any ideas about how to allow the cron-activated script reading my calender?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

I added several own log-commands to the scripts in order to trace 'Where am I and what values do my variables have'. After running through the scripts manually via command line and automatically via cron, I compared these logs and found out that when started by cron, several files couldn't be opened. The file names were given without any path, so they were expected to be in the path I called the first script from via commandline. When launched by cron, these files could not be opened, even though I added the relevant paths to PATH= and PYTHONPATH=

So what helped: try using absolute (and full) paths to any files you want to access.